# Votes 'range' filter in viewing questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, voting

I find that I am able to answer questions, in general, within a certain 'voted' range. The higher a question is voted in my areas of expertise, the more profound and therefore the less likely I have found myself to be in answering it. Perhaps other programmers feel this as well.

Often I just click the 'votes' tab under 'questions' and scroll down until I reach a good range of questions that I feel like I can answer, and sometimes I scroll up to the higher voted questions and try and learn a thing or two from the true gurus in my trade.

Therefore: Should there be a way on the 'votes' tab under 'questions' to easily view all the questions for a given tag based on whether its upvotes are within a certain range? I think this feature will greatly help those looking to serve others with answers and also learn from them.